# Hibernate inserts null for ID when using strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: java, hibernate, null, h2

Why is Hibernate inserts null value for the ID in the table.

```
@Id
@Getter
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

This is the Message I am getting when inserting somthing in table blabla ↓↓↓

> Hibernate: insert into blabla (id, bla1, bla2) values (null, ?, ?)

However when instad of using `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY` → `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO/SEQUANSE` I am getting this message ↓↓↓

> Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
>
> Hibernate: insert into blabla (bla1, bla2, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Does anyone know why it's like that because this null in ID place is causing an Exception when connecting to a database.

**Update:**

I've run my Application with `strategy = SEQUENCE and AUTO` but I am getting also an Exception

Database is `H2`

**Solution:**

you go to your `application.properties` file and add this line of code:

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @Eugene H2 database

Comment: @Eugene check out my Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your table hasn't been defined as an auto incremental PK.

Try to add this one to application.properties:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

Comment: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` this one line of code really helped me. Appreciate it!

Comment: btw I am using Spring Boot is it a problem when I add this line of code to my project?

Comment: Check your Spring boot framework in pom file, if it goes with JPA then it's fine because the default JPA implementation is Hibernate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Both these commands were fixed in Hibernate ORM 5.6.5.Final, older versions produce invalid SQL for a some historic reason, it was accepted by old versions of H2, but new versions throw an expected exception.

This version also has various other changes needed for recent versions of H2.

You need to upgrade `hibernate-core` to this or newer version.